# Delay in UITableViewCell touch response

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to implement a '**SETTINGS** page' like split view with a table view on the left and an image view on the right. Everything is fine but there is a delay in table view cell touch if try to tap it faster. `DidSelectRowAtIndex` path is not getting called but the cell blinks.

What I've tried,

1. moved *image changing* logic into `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` from `DidSelectRowAtIndex`
2. removed everything from delegate methods (to check whether is it due to loading
       of image)

How can I solve this wired problem?

**TableDatasource**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"tutorialCell";
        CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TutorialTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];        
        }
        NSDictionary * dic = [dictArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.tutorialText.text = [dic valueForKey:TUTORIAL_TEXT];
        cell.tutorialImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dic valueForKey:TUTORIAL_ICON]];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:@"#36393D" alpha:1.0];
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHex:@"#1f1f1f" alpha:1.0]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        return cell;
    }
```

**TableView Delegate**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary * dic = [dictArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _tutorialImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dic valueForKey:TUTORIAL_IMAGE]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UITableViews are subclasses of UIScrollViews which have `delaysContentTouches` enabled by default.  This is because the UIScrollView tries to figure out if the touch is part of a swipe gesture or scrolling action before allowing the touch to go to its subviews.  If you really want to disable that action you can, by setting the `delaysContentTouches` of your table view to NO.  This might make scrolling behave a little strangely because taps will *immediately* go to your table view's cells.  You might find that you actually like the delayed touch action better than the non-delayed touch action.

**Edit** Clement says he already tried that, so here's another idea.

In the posted code you're loading these images from disk (`imageNamed:`) at least initially.  UIKit might do some caching.  If your tutorial images are pretty big there might not be much you can do to load them faster, so load them ahead of time instead.  You can load all the images and put them in a dictionary using those same `[dic valueForKey:TUTORIAL_IMAGE]` keys.  Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can set `_tutorialImageView.image` to one of the (already loaded) images from the dictionary.

Comment: It is already set to NO in the interface builder, I even tried putting it inside 'viewdidload' but no changes in the behaviour.

Comment: @Clement OK, new suggestion in edit.  Also, have you tried profiling this code with Instruments?  If it really is a performance issue it would help to know the heaviest backtrace.

Comment: Thank you. Ill try your suggestions

Comment: it appears the individual contentViews have their own UIScrollView, which the tableView's delaysContentTouches does not affect and you must set per cell.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the image loading code. I have two suggestions here:

a. If the images are not too many, you could load them all and cache them in an NSArray for example.

b. If memory is a concern, I suggest first displaying a placeholder image and/or a UIActivityIndicator, then load the main image in a separate thread off the main thread.