# How to remove touch delay from custom UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom button where the image changes upon a press. This button is in the contentView of a UITableViewCell within a UITableView.

There is a noticeable delay when pressing the button before the image changes. Take the button out of the cell and into a UIView the change of image on press is instant.

How do I remove this delay?

It's worth pointing out that I have tried setting *delaysContentTouches* on the UITableView but it makes no difference that I can see.

Here is some test code that proves the issue. Create new project and add a UITableView to the storyboard.

```c
#import "JWViewController.h"

@implementation JWViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return 1; }
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { return return 65.0f; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple_selected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

I have searched and there appears to be a number of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642547/uibutton-touch-is-delayed-when-in-uiscrollview) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608796/delay-in-uitableviewcell-touch-response) relating to this but none with a working answer.

[This blog post](http://www.charlesharley.com/2013/programming/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell-has-no-highlight-state/) doesn't appear to work either in this simple case.

Comment: Does it work on iOS 6? When I wrote that post iOS 7 didn't exist. :o) I'll take a look...

Comment: Compiled my test app for 6 and I still get the delay.

Comment: Did you try logging the time for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView`? Maybe that would give you a clue on where things might be getting delayed.

Comment: @JMWhittaker : i've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21424391/2857130) on a similar question

Answer (score 1):

Finally got solution of your issue.

Try this, it will work fine.
Add steps in your existing code:- 
1.) Set tag of the button which is in content view.
2.) Add target on that button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return 1; }
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { return 65.0f; }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 65);
        button.tag = indexPath.row;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        return cell;
    }

    - (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]];

        for (UIView *currentView in cell.subviews)
        {
            if ([NSStringFromClass([currentView class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"])
            {
                UIScrollView *svTemp = (UIScrollView *) currentView;
                [svTemp setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is weird and redundant. Your `buttonPressed:` method will get called a ton of times, because you are using `UIControlEventAllTouchEvents` control event. Better to loop through your subviews in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I was able to use this as a starting point and add the following to my `UITableViewCell` subclass (in a setup method):  `if ([self.superview respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelaysContentTouches:)])
 {
  UIScrollView *svTemp = (UIScrollView *)self.superview;
  [svTemp setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29259705/1728552

Seems that the table view has another scrollview inside.

Answer (score -1):

Subclass UITableView, and implement only this method:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}
```

Then set `tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;`

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass the touch event directly to the button.

```
 [yourTableViewObject setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```

This disables scrolling of the table view when the button is touched. you can handle that by either using a Gesture recogniser or subclassing the tableview to implement

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
return YES;
}
```